# Publishing existing iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, mobileprovision

I'm taking over an existing published iOS application and have made changes to the application source code. Now it is time for me to publish the application to Test Flight as well as publish it to production.

I do have admin rights on iTunes connect and have been added to the clients organisation.

How can retrieve the p12 as well as mobile provision profiles so that I can publish the app?

Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can create certificates & provisioning profiles in the Apple Member Center after signing in: https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action

Answer (score 0):

You need admin rights on Apple Developer as well to generate a Distribution Certificate https://developer.apple.com/

Nicolas